# how to embed manifest file in executable without mt.exe?

Tags: windows, winapi

I don't have Visual Studio and I don't have Windows SDK, so I don't have mt.exe.
Is there a way to embed the manifest file in the executable without using mt.exe ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to compile source code into an executable program via a different compiler, then you can use the Win32 API [`UpdateResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx) function to modify the target .exe file and add/update an `RT_MANIFEST` resource in it as needed.  Otherwise, you will have to use a third-party resource editor, such as [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) or [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), to edit the target .exe file manually.