# How to change manifest in executable?

Tags: windows, manifest

I have two executable files, the first one should run the second one. The second one comes with different types of manifests: `asInvoker`, `requireAdministrator`, etc.
Is it possible to change the manifest of executable file? I'm searching a simple solution on `C`.
I would like not to keep few copies of executable with different types of manifests, and not to keep third party tool that could change it. BTW, it is possible and this tool exists: `MT` (manifest tool) from visual studio package, [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware%20link).

Comment: manifest - this is resource (Type=`RT_MANIFEST`, Name=`CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` (*for exe*) - you can use [`UpdateResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx) for replace , of course if exe not signed

Comment: My exe not signed, I'll check this function. On first look, seems perfect.
Of course it is for internal usage only.

Comment: Signing has nothing whatsoever to do with this, and you should not use the technique suggested by RbMm in real code. He just literally answered your question of how `mt.exe` does it, without considering that [wanting to do this is evidence of bad design or a misunderstanding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change the manifest file using `mt.exe` from the Win32 SDK. But that is *only* something you should do during development or testing. You cannot deploy this tool to customer's machine, so you can't use it to dynamically change the manifest back and forth.

But that's okay, because you don't ever need to change the manifest file back and forth at runtime. The executable's manifest file should specify the *minimum required privileges* for that EXE. Thus, if it's possible for the user to run the EXE without administrative privileges (i.e., without elevation)—even if it means the app runs with limited functionality—the app's manifest should specify "asInvoker". The user can always choose to run the app with administrative privileges if they need those extra features.

And, of course, you can launch the EXE programmatically with elevation. You do this using [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154.aspx), specifying the "runas" verb for the `lpVerb` parameter. This will have the same effect as setting the permissions level in the application's manifest to "requireAdministrator".

It is not entirely clear from your question how your application is set up. Normally, the first EXE has "asInvoker" set in its manifest so that any user can run it. It doesn't need administrative privileges in order to do anything. However, if there *is* something it might need to do that requires administrative privileges, it displays some bit of UI with the UAC shield icon, and clicking on that will launch a second EXE (with "requireAdministrator" set in its manifest) that performs whatever task requires elevation. This second app doesn't need to be distributed in an "asInvoker" form because what it does *always* requires elevation. You'll notice that this is how all of Microsoft's apps are set up, including the bits shipped with the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RbMm for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481825/how-to-change-manifest-in-executable#comment75958281_44481825%20comment).
Also I found later that my question is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855350/how-to-embed-manifest-file-in-executable-without-mt-exe). Sorry for that, I haven't found this earlier.

So, the solution (error handling and includes omitted):

```
HANDLE handle = BeginUpdateResourceW(file, TRUE);
UpdateResourceW(handle, RT_MANIFEST, CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), manifest, strlen(manifest));
EndUpdateResourceW(handle, FALSE);
```

Notes for further generations:

- Manifest should be in `short chars` - `char *` instead of `wchar *`
- Errors (e.g. incorrect XML syntax) could be tracked in `Event Viewer`, section `Windows Logs -> Application`
- Some tools (Resource Hacker) could open and show manifests, but they show unicode manifests without error too...